How to display a space in verbatim?
In this example, a space is not displayed in verbatim.
  %verbatim
    \catcode`\@=11%
    \def\verb{\expandafter\verb@make\string}%
    \def\verb@make#1{\begingroup\tt%
      \let\verb@delim=#1%  Save the delimiter.
      \def\verb@print##1{%
        \if##1\verb@delim% If we found the end delimiter, end the group.
          \def\verb@print{\def\verb@print{}\endgroup}%
        \else%
        ##1% Print the char
        \fi%
        \expandafter\verb@print\string% Continue reading the next char.
      }%
      \expandafter\verb@print\string% Start reading.
    }%
    \catcode`\@=12%
    %verbatim
    Some text.
    
    \verb|2014-12-18 00:12|
    
    \verb|2014-12-18[]00:12|
    
    Some text.
    \bye


you can not capture a normal space using an undelimited argument, you could make space catcode 12 but if changing catcodes you may as well change the catcode of other characters as well (like latex's \verb or the texbook \verbatim example)  then you would not need a loop and \string at all.  Or do you need the \string version, so it works in the arguments of other commands, in which case you need futurelet

I guess you don't want stringification of the subsequent token via \expandafter\verb@print\string any more when the verbatim-delimiter is found.

Why did you nest the definition of \verb@print  inside the definition of \verb@make?

\string leaves explicit space tokens (category 10, character code 32) unchanged while explicit space tokens are skipped when TeX is gathering the first token of an undelimited macro argument. That's why with your code spaces are skipped instead of making it into the typesetting as horizontal glue.

You can fix the immediate issue by using \let rather than an undelimited argument to gobble each character, that way you see space tokens, however it's not a true verbatim, you still lose spaces that are never tokenised eg the space after \foo. For that you would need to change the catcodes of all non-letters, like \verb in latex, or the\verbatim example in the texbook. However this loop does have the advantage of working within the arguments of other commands.

his example, a space is not displayed in verbatim.

  %verbatim
    \catcode`\@=11%
    \def\verb{\expandafter\verb@make\string}%
    \def\verb@make#1{\begingroup\tt%
      \let\verb@delim=#1%  Save the delimiter.
      \def\verb@print{\afterassignment\verb@@print\let\tmp= }%
      \def\verb@@print{%
        \ifx\tmp\verb@delim% If we found the end delimiter, end the group.
         \endgroup
        \else%
        \tmp% Print the char
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\verb@print\expandafter\string% Continue reading the next char.
        \fi%
      }%
      \expandafter\verb@print\string% Start reading.
    }%
    \catcode`\@=12%
    %verbatim
    Some text.
    
    \verb|2014-12-18 00:12|
    
    \verb|201{}4-12\foo -18[]00:12|

    \verb|verbatim stuff|{non-verbatim stuff in braces} 
    
    Some text.
    \bye



@UlrichDiez sigh I just changed the OP's code from using #1 to using \let I guess i should fix the end condition too, thanks.

@UlrichDiez thanks, fixed
